# Remove '\x...' characters from set in python

Tags: python

So, I've got a set containing unique characters from a string, but there are some characters that I don't want in it, specifically '\x...' characters. I tried to use regex but it didn't work for me, probably because I did something wrong, and the only way that works for me is removing each caracter individually.

Set:
`` {'\t', ' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '=', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '\x7f', '\x80', '\x82', '\x83', '\x84', '\x85', '\x86', '\x87', '\x88', '\x89', '\x8a', '\x8b', '\x8c', '\x8e', '\x91', '\x92', '\x93', '\x94', '\x95', '\x96', '\x97', '\x98', '\x99', '\x9a', '\x9b', '\x9c', '\x9e', '\x9f', '\xa0', '¡', '¢', '£', '¤', '¥', '¦', '§', '¨', '©', 'ª', '«', '¬', '\xad', '®', '¯', '°', '±', '²', '³', '´', 'µ', '¶', '·', '¸', '¹', 'º', '»', '¼', '½', '¾', '¿', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', '×', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï'} ``

Desired output:

`` {' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '=', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '¡', '¢', '£', '¤', '¥', '¦', '§', '¨', '©', 'ª', '«', '¬', '®', '¯', '°', '±', '²', '³', '´', 'µ', '¶', '·', '¸', '¹', 'º', '»', '¼', '½', '¾', '¿', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', '×', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï'} ``

Is there a better way to it other than do a set.discard() for each character I don't want?

Comment: You're seeing the difference between `repr` and `str`.  When Python prints out the contents of a container like `set`, it uses `repr` for each contained element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
Set2 = {ch for ch in Set if ch in string.printable}
```

Of course you can substitute your own string or set of allowable characters for `string.printable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with different decoding styles. In the example below only `\x7f` was not decoded.

```
result = set([ch.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("ascii") for ch in s ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
x=set(['\t'])
final_set=set()
for value in set:
   if value not in x:
      final_set.add(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but although that solves my specific problem, I wanted a more general solution, so that I don't need to add by hand any new strange character that I don't want in my string.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to filter out the unprintable characters.

```
>>> full = {'\t', ' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '=', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '\x7f', '\x80', '\x82', '\x83', '\x84', '\x85', '\x86', '\x87', '\x88', '\x89', '\x8a', '\x8b', '\x8c', '\x8e', '\x91', '\x92', '\x93', '\x94', '\x95', '\x96', '\x97', '\x98', '\x99', '\x9a', '\x9b', '\x9c', '\x9e', '\x9f', '\xa0', '¡', '¢', '£', '¤', '¥', '¦', '§', '¨', '©', 'ª', '«', '¬', '\xad', '®', '¯', '°', '±', '²', '³', '´', 'µ', '¶', '·', '¸', '¹', 'º', '»', '¼', '½', '¾', '¿', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', '×', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï'}
>>> printable = {' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '=', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '¡', '¢', '£', '¤', '¥', '¦', '§', '¨', '©', 'ª', '«', '¬', '®', '¯', '°', '±', '²', '³', '´', 'µ', '¶', '·', '¸', '¹', 'º', '»', '¼', '½', '¾', '¿', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', '×', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï'}
>>> full == printable
False
>>> set(filter(str.isprintable, full)) == printable
True
```

Using a set comprehension instead of the `filter` class,

```
>>> {x for x in full if x.isprintable()} == printable
True
```